# User Account with Administrative Access Mode cannot access Position

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

We have created a new user account with CAL Access Mode: ***Administrative*** and Security Role: ***System Administrator*** just for managing the user accounts in CRM 2015 on premise. But this user account doesn't have access to read or select the Position while creating user accounts. Since we have some business logic based on the selected position, we do not want to create user accounts without position. I am curious to know why Administrative account cannot access Position which is system entity.

Appreciate if you have any solution for this issue.

Thanks

[image: Position field on User form is locked.]

Comment: What does the user level have to do with the form field lock? Unless you have built logic that we can't see.

Comment: Verified with read-write access mode? Cross checked the business rules, JavaScript ??

Comment: With read-write access mode it works fine. And we don’t have any business rule or Javascript on this. User cannot see the Position entity itself from Advanced find.

Comment: This Position relationship is attached with hierarchy security model as well, not sure if product allows it for non license consuming (administrative) user.. I could not find any links to share though.. reach out to MS support ticket.